# How to only reload current file in Emacs Haskell Mode

Tags: haskell, emacs

In Emacs' Haskell-Mode, I can push `ctrl-c ctrl-l` to reload the current file in the REPL. Each time I do this, however, it compiles all the file's local dependencies (modules in the same folder), which takes a bit of time. Is there a simple way to reload only the current file/module and skip recompiling the others? It must be possible somehow, as my external dependencies don't need to be recompiled each time.

Comment: just `:r` right in the `REPL` buffer should work

Comment: Ah, great, that works fine. If you want to submit that as an answer I'll accept it. Surprised there's not an Emacs-Mode hotkey for it though.

Comment: @LogicChains: it's on the list: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/issues/807

Comment: Emacs hot key is `C-c-l`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch to the *REPL*-Buffer and just reload (`:r`) it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Recently `:reload` got its own keybinding: `C-c C-r`.